# Avoiding unrequired function declarations/definitions when using inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

After a long time of C-style procedural coding, I am just beginning to 'get' OOP. So I suspect there may be standard way of dealing with the situation I am facing. I have an application with the class hierarchy shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual int intf() { return 0;} // Only needed by B
  virtual double df() {return 0.0;} // Only needed by C
};    
class B : public A {
  int intf() {return 2;}
  // B objects have no use for df()
};    
class C : public B {
  double df() {return 3.14;}
  // C objects have no use for intf()
};    
int main(){
  // Main needs to instantiate both B and C.
  B b;
  C c;
  A* pa2b = &b;
  A* pa2c = &c;

  cout << pa2b->intf() << endl;
  cout << pa2b->df() << endl;
  cout << pa2c->intf() << endl;
  cout << pa2c->df() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now this program compiles and runs fine. However, I have question about its design. Class A is the common interface and does not need to be instantiated. Class B and C need to be. Regarding the functions: intf() is needed by B but not C, and df() is needed by C but not B. If I make intf() {df()} pure virtual in A, then there is no reasonable definition of df() {intf()} for B {C}.

**Edit**: *B and C share some data members and also some member functions other than f(). I have not shown it my stripped down code.*

Finally, as is standard, my application needs to access both B and C through a pointer to A. So my question is: Is there a way to 'clean up' this design so that unrequired/empty member function definitions (such as I have done in declaration/definition of A) can be eliminated? There is a clear "IS-A" relationship between the classes. So even though I share every newbie's thrill about inheritance, I dont feel I have stretched my design just so I could use inheritance.

Background in case it helps: I am implementing a regression suite. Class A implements functions and matrices common to every regression (such as dependent and independent variables). Class B is logistic regression with two classes ('0' and '1') and defines cost functions, and training algorithm for two-class logistic regression. Class C is multi-class logistic regression. It extends class B by training for multiple classes using the "one-vs-all" algorithm. So in a sense C is a binary logistic regression if you think of your class of interest as positive examples and all others as negative examples. Then you do it for every class to implement multi-class regression. The functions (intf and df) in question return the output. In case of logistic regression, the return value is a vector, while for multiclass regression, it is a matrix. And, as stated above, B and C dont have any use for each others' return functions. Except that I cant seem to be able to eliminate redundant definitions in A (the regression class).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You touched one of the most controversial point of OOP: the is-a == derivation pattern, resulting int the "god object" anti-pattern, since everything is ultimately a child-of-god, with god knowing every method of everyone and having an "answer" (read "default implementation") for everything.

"Is-a" is not enough to justify inheritance, where no replace-ability exist, but in real world no object is really fully replaceable with another, otherwise it will not be different.

You are in the "land of nowhere" where the substitution principle doesn't work well, but -at the same time- virtual functions look the best tool to implement dynamic dispatch.

The only thing you can do come to a compromise, and sacrifice one of the two.

As far the situation looks like, since B and C have nothing in common (no shared useful methods), simply don't let those method to originate from A.
If you have something to "share" is probably a runtime mechanism to discover the type of B or C before entering B related specific code or C related specific code.

This is typically done with a common base having a runtime-type indicator to switch upon, or just a virtual function (typically the destructor) to let dynamic_cast to be able to work.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}

    template<class T>
    T* is() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(this); }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int intf() { return 2; }
};

class C: public A
{
public:
    double df() { return 3.14; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    B b;
    C c;

    A* ba = &b;
    A* ca = &c;

    B* pb = ba->is<B>();
    if(pb) cout << pb->intf() << endl;

    C* pc = ca->is<C>();
    if(pc) cout << pc->df() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not have put my situation in better words. Deep down I understand that my design is far from ideal. The introductory textbooks I have been following mostly present the "god object" pattern. The relationships in my applications do not resemble the clean shape::circle examples I find in textbooks. I am not sure how much such clean relationships are encountered in real-life coding (I am guessing not much). One question: I recall reading that dynamic casting of objects is not a good design. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no runtime "discovery" here, you are just manually specifying the types you want to cast A to at compile time.  Why even have a "is<T>" method at all? just do the dynamic_cast where you want to cast it (would produce more readable code).  I can't say i agree with the path you've led the OP down, particularly because it does not provide polymorphic access to his common method...

Comment: @ryan0: yes, but this is due to the shortness of the sample. The fact `if(pb)` triggers depend on what ba points to. An this is runtime-dependent. The fact ba is initialized two rows above and is not taken from a million pointers container is incidental, not what I looked for.

Whatever other "static" implementation (including yours) makes B and C unrelated types, and hence impossible to be collected together (something the OP is looking at, since he wants a common ptr), unless implementing a "polymorphic adapter" - think to boost::any - that internally does nothing more of what I did here.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia As long as B and C derive from A, they can be collected together.  The fact that dynamic_cast does the type safety check at runtime doesn't really buy you anything.  You are still casting to a specific type where you want to use that type and that code is static.  You are doing static casting using dynamic_cast.  In fact if you used static_cast instead of the call to is<T> you wouldn't need the if(pb) check because the types would be validated before run time.  Your solution is unnecessarily complex, and does nothing to help the OP in learning proper class design.

Comment: @ryan0: "...Your solution is unnecessarily complex..." Sorry, but i'm not interested in any "my dick is longer then yours" show context. The only thing I note is that deriving from A<B> and A<C> does not create any common type that can be addressed by a same pointer type. My code is the "dual" of yours (that is in turn the "dual" of mine). Both have exactly the same semantic power or one indirection level. We just chose a different tool, and we both violate a requirement (not the same requirement, but one each). But this takes to much space to be demonstrated.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Fair enough.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Yeah, you are totally right!  A<int> and A<double> are different types, polymorphism would be impossible.  I stand fully corrected and ashamed.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the Liskov Substitution Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  It states that subclasses must fulfill the same contract as the superclass.  In your example, neither subclass does this.  The "Is-A" relationship is not enough to justify inheritance.

One option would be to use a single template method something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A<T> {
    T getValue();
}

class B : A<int> {
    int getValue();
}

class C: A<double> {
    double getValue();
}
```

this would allow the contract to be fulfilled by both subclasses while allowing the return type of the method to vary based on the subclass definition.

If you want to learn more object oriented programming "best practices", google "Robert Martin SOLID"

Comment: Maybe the confusion stems from the fact that in certain languages (like java), interfaces are used as a method of classification (where an interface doesn't define any methods but multiple objects implementing it can be regarded as objects of a similar "type").  In C++, interfaces don't exist and the only mechanism available is inheritance, which is a way stronger relationship.  This answer is spot on.

Comment: This is just another form of inheritance... form a "concept" instead form a "class". Since B and C have nothing in common let them have a method name in common. The beauty of OOP is that everything everyone agree to be wrong became good just after changing a name ... To me it is just hypocrisy!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I chose careful wording; it's not about replacing one object with another, it's about fulfulling the same contract, or implementing at minimum the same interface as the superclass.  If two different things have the same "operation" (in this case returning a value but maybe i'm oversimplifying it) then it's not unreasonable to give that operation a more "abstract" name and pull it up into an interface, so that the operation can be called polymorphically, which is what the OP wants to do.  You can do this with no "is-a" relationship at all.  Polymorphic behavior is the key.

Comment: @ryan0 Thanks. B and C aren't exactly substitutable with A. But they do share a lot of common functionality (which was not obvious in my stripped down code, I apologize). It is just that they differ in this one function. However, I seem to need to define this function up the inheritance chain if I need polymorphic access to it in my application.  One question about your code: Where to implement common member data and functions for B and C?

Comment: You can put the common members and functions in A (inheritance) or create a new object D that has the common functionality and give B and C an instance of D as a data member (composition).  Inheritance is probably fine for this case.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @ryan0. I am going to accept @emilio-garavaglia 's answer since he provided words to what I my thought process is. His answer also most directly solves my immediate problem, although I am not too sure about usage of `dynamic_cast<>`. Your solution looks more elegant to me but is above what I feel I can comfortably implement. I need to familiarize myself with templates. Thanks once again for your time to answer my questions.